# Multiple Bluetooth connect for IOS device

Tags: ios, bluetooth, gamekit

Recently, I use game kit to connect iPad ,then broadcasting video clips ,but when I want to connect multiple device, it can't work on final device.(ex: A as Master device , then b and c as slave ,when b connect to a ,then c connect a , this time b will disconnect).

Does anyone have any method so that I can connect multiple device on ios using game kit bluetooth?

Thanks

Comment: I have seen a question a few days ago on using iBeacon and also use bluetooth to transfer file at the same time. the iBeacon loses signal during the file transferring. There is a chance that the bluetooth on iOS device is not multitasking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Game Kit networking does not support more than one client at a time, look into Multipeer Connectivity framework. See http://nshipster.com/multipeer-connectivity/